# How can I obtain the following granular URL control in Django?

Tags: django

When my users log in I POST a form to:

```
mydomain.com/login
```

If the login fails, I wish to display the frontpage with an error message using the following code:

```
return render(request, 'mysite/index.html', {'loginError': True})
```

The frontpage displays correctly but the browser addressed bar shows:

```
mydomain.com/login
```

How can I get the address bar to display simply:

```
mydomain.com
```

Comment: Are you using django's auth system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) and make the homepage controller receive the flag as a parameter.

```
return redirect('/', loginError=True)
```

Also, consider using [messages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/) and/or the Django auth module.

Answer (score 0):

When the POST fails send a redirect back to whatever page you want.  This means you need somewhere some header to say "I am here because I was redirected because of such-and-such".

(Sorry my answer is not very Django-specific.  I am sure the framework provides some way to make the trick I just described work painlessly).